# Como alterar o arquivo style.xml delphi firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, xml, firemonkey

Queria saber como mudar este arquivo `style.xml` para alterar a barra de notificações do `android` no padrão material design (http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/).

Ou seja quero alterar o tema, mas sempre que altero este arquivo ele volta ao que era antes quero que minha aplicação receba este `theme`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

<!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

<!-- The rest of your attributes -->
```

Comment: tem certeza que isso é delphi ?

Comment: sim no delphi tem estes arquivos na pasta do projeto, mas quando este especificamente é manipulado ele é alterado para o padrao novamente. Creio que tenha alguma opção na ide que mude isso mas até agora não encontrei. Tanto que o AndroidManifest.template.xml pode ser alterado para adicionar admob

Comment: tentei efetuar algo parecido com isto http://www.theclub.com.br/restrito/revistas/201409/delp1409.aspx mas sem sucesso

Comment: talvez seja apenas a configuração dos arquivos, no Deployment. Tente alterar os arquivos por lá

Comment: não vi se a possibilidade alterar pelo deployement, tentei marcar uma opção para não alterar o conteudo o projeto nao compila, tentei informar outro arquivo style.xml e desabilitar o padrão também quando compila da erro, não me lembro do erro quando chegar em casa posto o erro. e uma questão importante está da interface a ide possibilita um ótimo desenvolvimento de app mas não adianta se interface ficar ultrapassada

Comment: eu vou falar por experiencia própria que passei na empresa que estou : não use delphi para android , vc vai ficar atrasadissmo nas tecnologias , as APIs para Java são muito melhores, tem anos de estudos, muitos contribuintes , o delphi já é o oposto ,tem pouquíssima ajuda pela internet, e em qualquer outro lugar, e muitos problemas que você ainda nem viu e vai se deparar.

Comment: entendo, obrigado pelo feedback (Y)

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki, conseguiu resolver essa questão do style.xml?... estou com o mesmo problema, altero o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml e quando recompilo ele altera as informações tudo de novo.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf infelizmente não, acabei desistindo disso

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki, não tem jeito, eu altero, quando vou fazer o deploy, começa dar conflito nos arquivos gerados a partir do xml. Deve ter um jeito de alterar o xml e recompilar sem dar problema. Qual o delphi que você usa?

Comment: estava usando o xe10, mas tentei de tudo, postei a duvida no forum da embarcadero e nada, ninguem soube resolver... acabei tendo que fazer o app em java no android studio que foi ate bem simples